# Displaying google maps locations. For loop iteration issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im creating a locations page using Google Maps API. Im checking to see if a location, based on my geolocation, is in a 50 mile radius. My calculations work. My issue is displaying the information of each location.

By default the page shows all locations.
If the user clicks 'use my location', the map will geocode their location and display it on the map and compare the mile in distance to all stores using the Haversine algorithm.
```

```
for(i = 0; i < locationData.length; i++){
    latCooridnate = Number(locationData[i].latitude);
    lngCooridnate = Number(locationData[i].longitude);
    milesFromGeolocation = distance(pos.lat, pos.lng, latCooridnate, lngCooridnate);
    searchRadius = Math.round( milesFromGeolocation * 10 ) / 10;
    testing = false;
    if(searchRadius <= 50){
         jQuery('.locations li').remove();
         testing = true;
         if (testing == true) {
              jQuery('.locations').append('<li id="'+ i +'" class="location-name"><div><p class="location-nickname">' + locationData[i].name + '</p><p class="address-part-one">' + locationData[i].address_part_one + '</p>' + addressPartTwo + '<p class="city-state-zip">' + locationData[i].city + ' ' + locationData[i].state + ' ' + locationData[i].zipcode + '</p><i style="float: left; margin-left: -25px; margin-top: 2px; color: #8fc2db;" class="fa fa-phone"></i><p class="phone-number">' + locationData[i].phone_number + '</p><i style="float: left; margin-left: -25px; margin-top: 2px; color: #8fc2db;" class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><p class="hours">' + currentDayWorkHours + '</p><p class="location-button"><a href="' + locationData[i].url + '">Book an Appointment</a></p><p class="view-location">View Locations Details ></p></div></li>');
         }
    }
};
```

When i console all the stores in a 50 mile radius, I'm seeing the correct stores. I think the jQuery append method is overwriting each time, instead of adding. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not got what is ur issue can add what issue u getting...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this line:

```
jQuery('.locations li').remove();
```

..before the loop, otherwise you will only see the last location

Comment: Should have noticed that. Thank you.